# Migrated Hybris storefront throws Server Error but log shows no error

Tags: internal-server-error, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

I'm migrating from a Hybris 5.2 to Hybris 6.5, so far we managed to get rid of compilation errors and erros when running the server, but so far we have been unable to access the storefront.

When we try to access it we get a server error, but the log doesn't show anything that could give us a hint. Even the Chrome console doesn't show any errors.

[image]

I include the logs generated from the ant clean all and the hybris server startup in [this link](https://experts.hybris.com/storage/attachments/10358-logs.zip).

I have even debugged the home page controller, but no exceptions are being thrown, and my guesses are small since I have no feedback on the possible issue at hand.

What do we have to look at in these kind of situations? Is there a way to track the issue? Any tool in Hybris or an external one that could help me sniff the problem?

Comment: have you tried `ant server` and `ant customize` before `ant clean all` ?

Comment: no, I'm not familiar with those commands, what do they do if it's not much asking ?

Comment: `ant server` : Configuring server `platform/tomcat using` config set at `config/tomcat`
`ant customize` : Copies all files from `/config/customize` folder to `/bin` folder recursively

Comment: try to add conditional breakpoint on org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl#write(java.lang.String, int, int) checking if the String contains 'Server Error' and maybe you will get some hint there.

Comment: I think the error comes from a JSP page. The JSP errors doesn't show in the log console. So try to write a very minimalistic JSP page and look if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to a missing configuration for JCO and SMTP, our client had a local.properties that had this configuration commented, after setting a configuration for these two the storefront was visible, still we don't understand how this missing configuration could not throw any error on console and we reached to this solution after a lot of trial and error.